# I want to convert image with multi-colors to two colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

As there a possible way to make a multi-colors PSD/AI/Image to be only two colors

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of ways. But that depends on what do you have, and want. So your question should be more clear. Perhaphs your specific case you are working now.

Comment: Yes it's possible. *How* depends upon the nature of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop:

- Use a Gradient Map
- Image -> Adjustments -> Posterize and set the number of colors you want to allow
- Manually select the parts and change the color

Illustrator:

- Image Trace - select 2 colors to use
- Manually change the colors